# only output columns with missing values and the percetage of it

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, isnull, targetnullvalue

I used this code to find the percentage of missing values in each column:

```
     df.isnull().mean().round(4).mul(100).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

The result shows all columns, which makes the output looks very long if you have a lot of columns and only need to know the percentage of the missing value ones.
I would like to know how to remove all the columns that have no missing values for this code.
Any other solutions are welcomed

---

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your nulls in an intermediate dataframe and use it for slicing:

```
nulls = df.isnull()
nulls.loc[:, nulls.any()].mean().round(4).mul(100).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

example input:

```
     a    b  c
0  0.0  1.0  2
1  3.0  NaN  4
2  NaN  5.0  6
```

output:

```
b    33.33
a    33.33
```

Answer (score 0):

You might simply filter what you get to only include columns which have more than 0 missing value, consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.0,2.0,3.0],'b':[4.0,float("nan"),float("nan")],'c':[float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan")]})
means = df.isnull().mean()
percentages = means[means>0].round(4).mul(100).sort_values(ascending=False)
print(percentages)
```

output

```
c    100.00
b     66.67
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is less efficient than filtering first as you need to compute the mean anyway ;) That would make a difference on large dataframes with not so many missing values

Comment: I assumed *which makes the output looks very long* in question is signal that concern is having redundant information rather than making run as fast as possible

Comment: Well, you can achieve both! But your answer is valid, just pointing out the potential drawback of filtering after ;)